# Como imprimir valores desse tipo de array

Tags: php, foreach

Este e o xml usado para gera o array

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <integracao>
        <status>2</status>
        <resposta>
            <paginacao>
                <totalItens>2</totalItens>
                <paginaAtual>1</paginaAtual>              
                <registrosPorPagina>10</registrosPorPagina>        
                <ultimaPagina>1</ultimaPagina>
            </paginacao>
            <historico>
                <registro>
                    <transacao>19569951</transacao>
                    <email></email>
                    <valor>2000</valor>        
                    <dataEmissao>2014-09-02T12:09:14</dataEmissao>       
                    <status>aguardando</status>
                    <codigoStatus>1</codigoStatus>
                </registro>
                <registro>
                    <transacao>19561474</transacao>
                    <email></email>
                    <valor>2000</valor> 
                    <dataEmissao>2014-09-01T01:09:20</dataEmissao>  
                    <status>aguardando</status>
                    <codigoStatus>1</codigoStatus>
                </registro>
            </historico>
        </resposta>
    </integracao>
```

Saída:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [status] => 2
    [resposta] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [paginacao] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [totalItens] => 4
                    [paginaAtual] => 1
                    [registrosPorPagina] => 10
                    [ultimaPagina] => 1
                )

            [historico] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [registro] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [transacao] => 19605633
                                    [email] => alexandre@uniaomaker.com.br
                                    [valor] => 500
                                    [dataEmissao] => 2014-09-04T01:09:25
                                    [status] => aguardando
                                    [codigoStatus] => 1
                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [transacao] => 19605619
                                    [email] => email_cliente
                                    [valor] => 500
                                    [dataEmissao] => 2014-09-04T01:09:14
                                    [status] => cancelado
                                    [codigoStatus] => 8
                                )

                            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [transacao] => 19569951
                                    [email] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [valor] => 2000
                                    [dataEmissao] => 2014-09-02T12:09:14
                                    [status] => aguardando
                                    [codigoStatus] => 1
                                )

                            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [transacao] => 19561474
                                    [email] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [valor] => 2000
                                    [dataEmissao] => 2014-09-01T01:09:20
                                    [status] => aguardando
                                    [codigoStatus] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso não é um array, é um objeto [SimpleXMLElement](http://www.php.net/SimpleXMLElement) o qual pode ser iterado tal qual um array, mas não através da mesma notação de colchetes que um.

Como não tenho o mesmo XML que você para lhe oferecer uma solução 100% precisa, experimente algo como:

```
echo $sxml -> status; // Deve retornar 2
```

Se precisar dos dados da entrada **resposta**, use como argumento de um foreach:

```
foreach( $sxml -> resposta as $nodes ) {

    // Use $nodes -> paginacao
}
```

Se, porventura, você realmente fizer questão de trabalhar com esses dados como um array, você pode converter esse objeto SimpleXMLElement para um array com uma função-zinha bem bacana:

```
function map( $param ) {

    if( is_object( $param ) ) {
        $param = get_object_vars( $param );
    }

    if( is_array( $param ) ) {
        return array_map( __FUNCTION__, $param );
    }

    return $param;
}

$array = map( $sxml );
```

Sendo **$sxml** a variável com o objeto SimpleXMLElement.

Mas isso não é nenhum pouco recomendável porque você passa a não ter mais acesso aos recursos da SimpleXML e nem pode, caso venha a ser necessário, importar o objeto em questão para a [DOM](http://www.php.net/DOM) que oferece uma gama de recursos muito maior para se trabalhar.

Comment: adicionei o aquivo xml no post

Comment: Eu chutei a sintaxe, mas é bem isso mesmo.

Comment: e como que faz para usar esta segunda função?

Comment: Ooops, faltou isso né? Vou adicionar, mas é como qualquer outra função. ;)